# Swift: Extra argument in call

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm converting some working Objective-c code to Swift. It's all ported but I'm getting an error on this line:

```
var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit, fromDate: start, toDate: end, options: 0)
```

It tells me `toDate` is an extra argument but the method was generated by code completion so I'm sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a message often is really confusing. It often means, that one of your parameter's value has a different type then it should have.

Here, your value "0" as options-parameter isn't valid. This parameter wants an `NSCalendarOptions.allZeros`(in your case), another `NSCalendarOptions`-value, or `nil`:

```
var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit, fromDate: start, toDate: end, options: NSCalendarOptions.allZeros)

var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit, fromDate: start, toDate: end, options: nil)
```